# Why is this print line command executing twice?

Tags: java, graphics, queue

I have the code below.

It all works, but annoyingly, the print line command in the `while` loop runs twice. There is (and I have tested for it), only unique items in the queue, no duplicates.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    boolean isParent;

    int drawCount = 1;

    int x = 0, y = 0, width = 0, height = 0;
    Color colour;

    while (!qtreeQueue.empty()) {

        drawNode = (QuadTreeNode) qtreeQueue.deque();
        isParent = drawNode.getIsParent();

        if (!isParent) {
            x = drawNode.getRectangle().x;
            y = drawNode.getRectangle().y;
            width = drawNode.getRectangle().width;
            height = drawNode.getRectangle().height;
            colour = getRectangleColour(drawNode);
            System.out.println(drawCount + ". Drawing: x = " + x + "; y = " + y + 
                    "; width = " + width + "; height = " + height + 
                    "; colour = " + colour.toString());
            minMax(drawNode);
            g.setColor(colour);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            drawCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Minimum level of tree: " + min + "\nMaximum level: " + max);
}
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What class is `qtreeQueue` from? Is it one of your own classes? The only two things that come to mind for me is that either there's a problem with the `empty()` method of it or the `paint` is called twice in quick succession. The latter might be the case if the queue is always filled before a paint.

Comment: Yep I haven't read that paint() is called twice anywhere but I guess it must be.

Comment: Any event triggers a `repaint()`, that one I did know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means the `paint` method is being called twice, which is perfectly normal. The system can call `paint` as many times as it wants, so you shouldn't perform any operation that might change the state of your program within that method.

Comment: @AlexW: `paint` is meant *only* to refresh the contents of the screen. You should perform all updates and other operations (`deque`, `println` etc.) in a separate method and call it whenever your actual data has changed. The system can call `paint` any time a portion of the screen needs to be redrawn, for eg. if the window is maximized or moved.

Comment: But if I call a method from paint to do this it would do it twice still? By the way this only happens in depth first search. Breadth first doesn't repeat.

Comment: @AlexW: It *could* still happen -- you shouldn't be mixing your search operations and `paint`. Perform your search, store all the results in some kind of data structure, then inside `paint` simply display these results.